# Why does control+D no longer prompt me for a folder to save to?

Tags: google-chrome

I used to use ctrl+D to bookmark pages and chrome would prompt me which folder to save to. Now it doesn't do that anymore; it just chooses the Bookmarks Bar seemingly arbitrarily. Also, if I used ctrl+D on an already-bookmarked page it would allow me to change the folder, or un-bookmark it. Now it just does nothing if the page is already bookmarked.

Is this due to an update, a bug, or some configuration setting that went wrong?

(This is on Windows 10 if it matters)

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using ? Have you tried resetting it atleast ? Or create a new profile for Chrome ?

Answer (score 0):

Check our your keyboard shortcut settings in Chrome.

Goto  `chrome://extensions`

Scroll to the very bottom and there is a `Keyboard shortcuts` link.  You can change keyboard shortcuts here.

Then check `chrome://flags` and search for `Enable Enhanced Bookmarks` - set it to disable

Restart Chrome and give it another try

Answer (score 0):

Oops, my entire Windows install seems to be hosed. This issue in Chrome just happened to be the first thing I noticed. I will close this as "too localized".